How to aligh PHP snippet used in cartflows, wordpress to the right side (see picture)
I would like to move the gaetway icons and paypal logo to the right side of the table. I have added this thourgh code snippets plug in using this code:
function add_credit_card_gateway_icons( $icon_string, $gateway_id ) {

if ( 'stripe' === $gateway_id ) {

$icon_string  =  ' <img class="stripe-visa-icon stripe-icon" src="' . WC_STRIPE_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/images/visa.svg" alt="Visa" /> ' ;
$icon_string .= ' <img class="stripe-mastercard-icon stripe-icon" src="' . WC_STRIPE_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/images/mastercard.svg" alt="mastercard" /> ' ;
$icon_string .= ' <img class="stripe-amex-icon stripe-icon" src="' . WC_STRIPE_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/images/amex.svg" alt="amex" /> ' ;
$icon_string .= ' <img class="stripe-discover-icon stripe-icon" src="' . WC_STRIPE_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/images/discover.svg" alt="Discover" /> ' ;
$icon_string .= ' <img class="stripe-jcb-icon stripe-icon" src="' . WC_STRIPE_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/images/jcb.svg" alt="jcb" /> ' ;

}
return $icon_string;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', 'add_credit_card_gateway_icons', 9, 2 );

function woocommerce_paypal_payments_gateway_icon( $icon, $id ) {
    if ( $id === 'ppcp-gateway' ) {
        return '<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/Logo/pp-logo-100px.png" alt="PayPal Payments" />'; 
    } else {
        return $icon;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', 'woocommerce_paypal_payments_gateway_icon', 10, 2 );


i tried to insert align right but I am not so good with coding.
